# How to check MFA status in Active Directory (Azure)?

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api

Please, tell me how to check users' MFA status in Active Directory via Graph API?

Comment: There is no direct way to know MFA status of a user. This article may help you, https://o365reports.com/2022/04/27/get-mfa-status-of-office-365-users-using-microsoft-graph-powershell/#:~:text=Microsoft%20Graph%20does%20not%20provide,the%20bottom%20of%20the%20blog.

Comment: That page describes the List of Authentication Methods Supported by Microsoft Graph (for example, PasswordAuthenticationMethod, PhoneAuthenticationMethod, etc.). How can I use these methods in the Graph API?

Comment: You haven't read the whole page - it talks of getting an export of user and their attributes, from which you could infer MFA info, but as said earlier and at the start of that page, there is no way to know 'status' of MFA using Graph API.  Refer [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/17374)

Comment: Could you include few more details in Qns like what you tried and where you stuck with errors?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above comments there is no API as of now to directly check the MFA status, but you can raise a feature request for the same [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

but if you want to check the MFS status using azure portal:

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#view-the-status-for-a-user